# How do you move in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm new to Minecraft's creative mode. I know how to fly and go down, but can't figure out other movements.  What other ways to move are there?

Answer (score 10):

The main controls are the same as in survival mode; by default:

- <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to move around
- <kbd>Space</kbd> to jump
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> to crouch

In creative mode specifically, you can double-tap <kbd>Space</kbd> to start flying; when flying, <kbd>Space</kbd> will ascend and <kbd>Shift</kbd> will descend. To stop flying, you can double-tap space again.

If you've changed these controls in the Options screen, you'll have to view the options screen yourself to see what you changed them to.